# Rigid body simulation explodes instead of collapsing

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I want a part of a dinosaur to collapse so that the bones fall to the ground and bounce a few times. I have enabled a rigid body simulation for each bone. The problem is that the bones seem to bounce off each other and get thrown away. But they should just fall down from gravity. Thanks for your help!

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-cmkL6WfH07)

[image: Rigid Body Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the bones,

- ```
  Bounciness 0,
  ```
- ```
  Sensitivity/Margin to 0.
  ```

Object/Rigid Body/Copy from Active.

[image]